# No Viable Overloaded +=, why?

Tags: c++

addition for a user defined type was defined by operator+, but += does not resolve to it, why?

```
typedef std::array<std::uint64_t,4> myvec_t;

inline myvec_t operator+(myvec_t foo, myvec_t bar){return mod_add(foo,bar);}

myvec_t a,b; 
a+=b; // g++ says: error: no viable overloaded '+='
```

EDIT: several people sufficiently answered the narrow question, I will 
accept an answer which explains why did the standard allow people to overload '+='(a,b) to do something different from 
a=a+b ?

Comment: The `+=` operator is a *separate* operator, it's not `+` followed by assignment.

Comment: Just wait for C++ 20 where you only need to program the <==> operator

Comment: @ArneJ Is `<==>` really a thing in C++20? It looks similar to the new `<=>` operator, but that's for comparisons.

Comment: In fact, for binary arithmetic operators (like `+`) [this canonical implementations reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) says that one should implement the operator through the combined assignment operator. That is your `operator+` should use `operator+=` in its implementation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you're right, got a '=' to much in my post

Comment: @ArneJ Still, how will that operator have an affect on the topic at hand?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK, I understand, one can write some operator+= which does something different from what operator+ followed by operator= would do. The question is then, why did the standard allow this at all?

Comment: Unrelated: `mod_add` is a free floating `friend` of `myvec_t`, right? Why?

Comment: @Kostas What do you mean by "why did the standard allow this at all?" Allow what? Do you mean that it allows `a += b` to do something different from `a = a + b`? Then the standard doesn't really *allow* it, but it also doesn't *forbid* it. If you as the programmer want `+=` do do something different from `+` followed by `=` then that's up to you. It's bad and will lead to confusion, but it's up to you. C++ doesn't hinder you in doing what you want, and if you want to shoot yourself in the foot then (again) it's up to you.

Comment: @Kostas why not allow it? In `+=` you can reuse existing memory instead of creating a new object and assigning it to `this`, while `+` doesn't need to return myvec_t (i.e. string builder like pattern).

Comment: @TedLyngmo right again, I guess I was really distracted when I wrote that post

Comment: @Kostas, operator overloading is available in C++ since its 1.0 version. I find no mention in _The Design and Evolution of C++_ about the reason for which `+` and `+=` are independently overloadable, so I doubt you'll find an authoritative answer to your why? question.

Comment: @Kostas It allows `a += b` to have the same *result* as `a = a + b`, but a different implementation, e.g. avoiding intermediate copies.

Comment: @Caleth The standard, and I am pretty sure, does not say anything whether any particular construct leads to a memory copy or not. It is 100% up to compiler writers, and I am also pretty sure that modern compilers emit exact same code in all of those cases. Most likely even all those "pass by reference" stuff that people tend to insert do nothing to the assembler output, esp. in a function marked "inline".

Answer (score 1):

You declare/define an overload for `operator+` and pass and `return` copies:

```
inline myvec_t operator+(myvec_t foo, myvec_t bar){return mod_add(foo,bar);}
```

you want to overload `operator+=` and pass and `return` references (assuming `mod_add` returns its result):

```
inline myvec_t& operator+=(myvec_t& foo, const myvec_t& bar)
{
    foo = mod_add(foo, bar);
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't proved an overload for `operator+=`, you provided an overaload for `operator+`

`operator+=` overaload is done with

```
inline myvec_t& operator+=(myvec_t& foo, const myvec_t& bar)
{
   foo = mod_add(foo,bar);
   return foo;
}
```

Note that your `operator+` implementation is very inefficent because it copies both operand and return a copy of the object while should make 1 only copy in total (the latter).

Comment: Explain downvlote please